# JsonConverter, Error Object Required when key doe not exists

Tags: json, vba, rest, api, jsonconverter

I am using connect VBA with API and sometime the JSON that got returned from the API has dynamic keys for example.
like this

```
json =[{"oeange":"good",}{"banana":{"color":"yellow"}},{"cat":"grumpy"}]
```

and sometime like this

```
json = [{"oeange":"good",}{"banana":null},{"cat":"grumpy"}]
```

I tried

```
for each item in json
 if item("banana").Exists("color") Then
    do something
End If

Next
```

it always give error object required. i looks like it always look for the ("color")

The question is how can I get the data either "null" or "yellow" from the json.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a recursive sub that would test what each structure was within the JSON and handle appropriately. Also, you need to shift the position of the trailing "," at the start so it actually separates items in the JSON.

So in A1 and A2 I have the following:

```
[{"oeange":"good"},{"banana":{"color":"yellow"}},{"cat":"grumpy"}]
[{"oeange":"good"},{"banana":null},{"cat":"grumpy"}]
```

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public r As Long
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim json As Object, jsonSource(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet, arr() As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    jsonSource = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A2").Value)

    For i = LBound(jsonSource) To UBound(jsonSource)
      Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource(i))
      EmptyJSON json
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub EmptyJSON(ByVal json As Object)
    Dim key As Variant, item As Object
    Select Case TypeName(json)
    Case "Dictionary"
        For Each key In json
            Select Case TypeName(json(key))
            Case "Dictionary"
                EmptyJSON json(key)
            Case Else
                r = r + 1
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .Cells(r, 2) = key
                    .Cells(r, 3) = json(key)
                End With
            End Select
        Next
    Case "Collection"
        For Each item In json
            EmptyJSON item
        Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful but I am very new to VBA. How do I extract the json(key) in to Cells. I tried numbers of ways. for example , I put i into EmptyJSON function but the I does not increase, even though I stated that i=i+1 after the Debug.Print key , , json(key)

Comment: Please see edit. Any further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: I have one more  question. What exactly the Application.Transpose do. I try to get rid of it because in Excel 2010 when there is quite large data it throw type mismatch. I have done some research it is because Transpose can not handle the large data so I am thinking to find an alternative way of doing that, instead of using the Transpose.  thank you very much.

Comment: It was to generate a 1d array to loop over. Other wise remove the transpose and then your array will be 2D and you will need to loop the first dimension i.e. For i = LBound(jsonSource,1) To UBound(jsonSource,1) :  Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource(i,1))

Comment: Please remember to accept answer to your questions.